# creating numpy array with first and last elements different and all other elements the same

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to create the following type of array

```
N = 5 # size of the array
eta = 2
a00 = 1 # first element of array
a0N = 3 # last element of array
# all entries should be 'eta' except the first and the last one
diag = [a00, eta, eta, eta, a0N]
```

I know how to create array that has eta as all its entries as follows.

```
diag = np.zeros(N) + eta
```

Will I be able to create what I want using 
`np.zeros(N)` or will I have to use a more low level constructor such as `numpy.ndarray`? .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built in method for this kind of array. This is a pretty standard way of doing it.

```
N = 5 # size of the array
eta = 2
a00 = 1 # first element of array
a0N = 3 # last element of array

# make a vector of 'etas', then change the first and last element
diag = np.ones(N,)*eta
diag[0] = a00
diag[-1] = a0N
```

Another workaround would be to make a list of the elements in your desired array. Then you can cast it as an array with np.array, as shown:

```
list_diag = [a00] + [eta for i in range(N-2)] + [a0N]
diag = np.array(list_diag)
```

Note: the latter solution might look cute, but will be much slower as N gets larger.

Comment: For large `N`, `np.zeros( (N,) ) + eta` would be faster than `np.ones( (N,) ) * eta`

Comment: Instead of `np.ones(N)*eta`, you can use `np.full(N, eta)`.  (Requires numpy version 1.8.0 or later.)